# IOS: Drag more than one image

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I try to make more than one image dragable in my iPhone-App. I have followed a tutorial on YouTube but it doesn´t work.

I create the images this way:

```
image1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_klein.png"]];
[image1 setFrame:CGRectMake(touchPoint.x-25,touchPoint.y-25,50,50)]; 
[[self view] addSubview:image1];

image2=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button2_klein.png"]];
[image2 setFrame:CGRectMake(135,215,50,50)];
[[self view] addSubview:image2];
```

And then I tried to make them dragable this way:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];

    if ([myTouch view] == image1) {
        image1.center = location;
        NSLog(@"Test1");
    }
    if ([myTouch view] == image2) {
        image2.center = location;
        NSLog(@"Test2");
    }
}
```

But it doesn´t work. When I tried to make one image dragable, it worked.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    image1.center = [myTouch locationInView:myTouch.view];
}
```

Can anybody tell me, where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

`UITouch.view` returns the view that's "handling" the touch (more or less the view returned by `-hitTest:withEvent:`. In this case, it is `self`, not `image1` or `image2`. (You can check this by breakpointing -touchesMoved:withEvent: and inspecting the touches yourself.)

You'll want to do something like

```
if ([image1 pointInside:[myTouch locationInView:image1] withEvent:event]) {
  ...
} else if ([image2 pointInside: ...]) {
  ...
}
```

Note that the touch can be inside both views; I've handled this by choosing image1 by default, but you'll have to decide what's "right".

Answer (score -3):

`image1` and `image2` are `UIImageView`s, you can not compare it against a `[(UITouch*) view]` (which is a `UIView`). So the comparison never happens, which means the two `if` conditions are not overridden.

Try putting `image1` and `image2` inside 2 `UIView`s named `image1View` and `image2View` , and your code would become `if ([myTouch view]==image1View) image1View.center=location` and so on.

Comment: Of course you can. UIImageView subclasses UIView, and of course, you can compare any pointer to any other pointer. "The comparison never happens" never happens.